# How does the Unix "fsck" differ from the Windows "chkdsk"?

Tags: filesystems, fsck

What are the differences between Unix's `fsck` and Windows' `chkdsk`?

Comment: I got rid of the Windows-specific parts of your question; if you want to ask about `chkdsk` itself try [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The internal structure of filesystems is totally different among each other, so different programs are needed for different filesystems. Even on UNIX/Linux systems there is a dedicated filesystem check program for every filesystem implementation (ext*, xfs, jfs, etc.)

Normally the initial command chkdsk/fsck checks the format of the underlying filesystem and then calls the dedicated check program.

Comment: xfs? jfs? are those better descendants of ffs than ext?

Comment: Different filesystems - but it would be too lengthy here (and the wrong subject) to tell you all about different filesystems and it is all on Wikipedia.